# Range of $x \cos(x)$

Tags: functions

What is the range of $x \cos(x)$ ?

My thinking is that maximum vale of $\cos(x)$ is $1$ and minimum value is $-1$ but $x$ can take any value from $-\infty$  to $+\infty$ but $\cos(x)$ is undefined at $\infty$.

Comment: A few corrections. $\cos x$ is a function from $\mathbb R\to [-1,1]\subset\mathbb R$. It is not defined on $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ so obviously, there is no $\cos(\infty)$ as it is not part of the domain. $x\cos x$ is a function from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, so the same logic applies. As such, there is no maximum or minimum.

Comment: I think that Range should be $R$ but why ? No answer from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range is all real numbers because
$x\cos(x)$
gets arbitrarily large
(consider $x=2n\pi$
and $x=(2n+1)\pi$)
and it is continuous,
so it assumes all values
between its local extrema.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is via drawing graph. First draw graph of $\cos x$ (periodic function) which is bounded between $-1$ and $1$. Now draw $y=\pm x$(non-periodic) which guides the amplitude of $\cos x$ and makes the resulting graph unbounded.